# Xcode linking failure message - what does it mean?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am receiving the following error message:
 **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

This is happening with Apple's 'Your third iOS app' demo program.  There are no dynamic errors displayed.  The error message detail goes on to say;
**ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_STESimpleTextDocument._documentText in /Users/chris/Library/...**

I've looked carefully thru the code at the _documentText ivar, as well as cut & pasted code from Apple's documentation, and I still get the same error??

Comment: Looks like you could be having a library issue

Comment: Is that the entirety of the error message detail?

Comment: You'd have to show us all of the definitions of _documentText that you've made and where you've done that (e.g. .h vs .m). I've seen these sorts of dupe symbol errors in code that's sloppy defining some constants (e.g. forgetting the "static"), but glancing at the "Your Third iOS app" pages, I don't see that sort of opportunity, so I'm not sure. Hard to diagnose without code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once, when I was coding late at night, I accidentally typed

```
#import "fubar.m"
```

instead of

```
#import "fubar.h"
```

in a "fubar2.m" file,

and got this kind of bizarre linker error.

The compiler was compiling the class methods once when it read "fubar2.m" and again when it read fubar.m.

I'm ashamed to say, I had to walk away from the project and come back to it before I found this error.

Comment: Ka ching! It turns out that my error was similar. I typed #import "STESimpleTextDocument.m" instead of .h in a header file.  This has the effect of trying to compile the class twice, hence the 'duplicate symbol'